# Can the rovers on Mars see the comet flyby?

Tags: mars, rovers, curiosity, spacecraft, comet

[image: source:[astrobob](http://areavoices.com/2013/09/25/countdown-to-comet-ison-mars-flyby/)]

Within a few days **Comet ISON** is going to make a close *flyby of Mars*.

Will the rovers on Mars have a chance to take a look at the comet as it approaches Mars?

Answer (score 10):

There are a total of 4 Martian spacecraft that have promised to attempt a photo, according to [this article](http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/508822/20130925/2013-comet-ison-mars-spacecraft-capture-images.htm#.UkLheH9jHSg).

- Mars Express- Will look for a total of 2 weeks, it started this week (On Monday)
- MRO- HiRISE camera will take 3 photos, at closest approach and the day before and after.
- Curiosity and Opportunity will both attempt a photo as well.

In fact, at least [HiRISE](http://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/releases/ison.php) has released it's pictures. They are dim and noisy, but here they are:

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to the HiRISE images: http://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/releases/ison.php